# WP8 set preview resolution

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8, resolution

On my Lumia 920 `GetAvailablePreviewResolutions()` returns that the following 4 resolutions are available for the target device:

- 1280x720
- 1024x768
- 800x448
- 640x480

but `SetPreviewResolutionAsync()` accepts only 1024x768. For the other three (supported) resolutions it throws an exception

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

I have restarted my phone but it doesn't seem to help either.

==========================================================================

For future developers who face the same problem, below are my findings.

Nokia Lumia 920 supports the following 6 capture resolutions (with their corresponding aspect ratio):

```
3264X2448        4:3;
3552X2000       16:9;
2592X1936        4:3;
2592X1456       16:9 ;
2048X1536        4:3 ;
640X480          4:3 ;
```

and following 4 preview resolutions (with their corresponding aspect ratio):

```
1280X720        16:9; 
1024X768         4:3 ;   
800X448         16:9 ;    
640X480          4:3;
```

for 16:9 aspect ratio capture_resolutions use only the 16:9 preview_resolutions.

Ref: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!advanced-photo-capturing.html

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.photocapturedevice.setpreviewresolutionasync(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future developers who face the same problem, below are my findings.

Nokia Lumia 920 supports the following 6 capture resolutions (with their corresponding aspect ratio):

```
3264X2448        4:3;
3552X2000       16:9;
2592X1936        4:3;
2592X1456       16:9 ;
2048X1536        4:3 ;
640X480          4:3 ;
```

and following 4 preview resolutions (with their corresponding aspect ratio):

```
1280X720        16:9; 
1024X768         4:3 ;   
800X448         16:9 ;    
640X480          4:3;
```

for 16:9 aspect ratio capture_resolutions use only the 16:9 preview_resolutions.

Ref: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!advanced-photo-capturing.html

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.photocapturedevice.setpreviewresolutionasync(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: There's a few exceptions to the case. The Lumia 820 have a firmware bug where it reports 720p as a supported capturer. The same problem applies to other platforms. Capturer and Preview resolutions doesn't always match.